# Debuggin in puppet fails 'boost::locale::conv::invalid_charset_error'

Tags: centos, puppet

OS: Oracle Linux Server release 7.1

Puppet --version: 4.10.10

When doing a puppet apply with -d option debugging terminates with below error.

```
Debug: Loading external facts from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::locale::conv::invalid_charset_error'
  what():  Invalid or unsupported charset:ANSI_X3.4-1968
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Have anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: My first guess would be that one of the fact implementations in `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d` is throwing that error.  You could try running them manually.  You might also check the machine's default locale settings.  ANSI X3.4 1968 is the original edition of (7-bit) ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

```
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

This solved the issue.